# How do I find out what version of the mysql odbc driver isql is using

Tags: mysql, linux, odbc

After finding a pretty nasty bug in the packaged 3.51.15 driver that came with ubuntu I downloaded and compiled the latest version from mysql's site.

Now im wondering how I can find out what version isql is actually using.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
ldd /path/to/isql
```

That should tell you which dynamic libraries it's linked against.  Find the mysql/odbc one and then plug that into google and that should give you an idea of what version it's using.